# How to prevent feasibility of intermolecular attack of 1,2-diol?

Tags: organic-chemistry

I was given a problem that requires me to synthesize (*1R,2R*)-2-methoxycyclohexanol from cyclohexene. I tried it with *syn*-hydroxylation of alkene $\pi$ bond with $\ce{OsO4}$ and NMO then directly transformed the hydroxyl group to methoxy group with $\ce{NaOH}$ and $\ce{CH3I}$.

During the protonation of one hydroxyl group, I notice that it would be attacked from the other hydroxyl group and I think it would make ring closure, which is what I do not want. Is the intermolecular attack of 1,2-diol feasible on any starting material (cyclic or polycyclic)? How to prevent the intermolecular attack to get desired product?

Comment: Huh? You worry about epoxy and not about selectivity?

Comment: @Mithoron I do not think I need to concern selectivity issue because the $\ce{CH3I}$ is one equivalent thus it will not methoxylate both of hydroxyl groups.

Comment: @Mithoron Oh, protecting group (i.e. TMSCl, py)? But is it a solution for that problem?

Comment: Why not form the epoxide from the alkene and open that with methoxide or PTSA/MeOH?

Comment: @Waylander Does the ring open via SN2 mechanism so the $\ce{OMe}$ group will be inverted? Or the PTSA will make the $\ce{OMe}$ on retention?

Comment: Basic MeO- opening is SN2. Acidic MeOH opening goes via protonation and a carbocation intermediate so you will lose the stereochemical integrity that way. MeO- is a poor leaving group. I don't think you would have any great problem with your original idea, except for a bit of dimethoxylation pulling your yield down

Comment: @Waylander Ah, the product in the problem is (1R,2R)-2-methoxycyclohexanol, the opening makes the product is (1R-2S).

Comment: Then go with your original route, you will not get epoxide formation. Form the monoanion with 1eq of NaH, quench with MeI. You will get a bit of di-OMe and a bit of recovered diol and no epoxide

Comment: @Waylander I think the original route looks good. Thank you for helping me.